# What was on Aladdin's list?

Tags: translation, aladdin

I was rereading [this great answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/68360/26325) about the movie *Aladdin* when this quote from the script caught my eye:

> So what you wish I really want to know
>
> You got a wish that's three miles long, no doubt
>
> So all you gotta do is rub like so, and oh!
>
> (GENIE imitates what he is calling ALADDIN, then turns into a certificate which rolls up and surrounds ALADDIN. GENIE pulls a list {**written in Arabic**} out of ALADDIN's ear, which he uses to rub his behind like drying off after a shower.)

Did that list written in Arabic actually say anything meaningful or was it just a bunch of garbage Arabic letters? You can see the list come out around 1:50. Granted it is really hard to read the writing.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm no expert in Arabic writing, but aren't the letters supposed to connect?  That looks like somebody looked at an image of the Arabic abjad and then drew a bunch of the symbols next to each other at random.

Comment: @Kevin I assumed as much when I watched the movie as a kid, but when I read that quote from the script where they specified Arabic I was thinking maybe there is some gold there instead of the pyrite I originally thought.

Comment: If you spotted that "as a kid" then you are way ahead of kid!me.

Comment: Technically, it's not Aladdin's list. Genie _expected_ Aladdin to have a list: "You got a wish that's three miles long, **no doubt**" Genie isn't sure about Aladdin, it's just very common to have a long wishlist according to him. Going by that logic, the list could not have contained anything meaningful, as it is not an actual wishlist, it's merely a visual prop (in-universe) used by Genie.

Comment: @Flater sure but since the prop had writing on it so what did Genie think was on Aladdin's list

Answer (score 2):

You really pay attention in details. It's not random letters. In the end of ribbon [درود به الله] is visible that means [Peace be upon Allah]. In fact Genie want to say forget god and ask from me!

Comment: درود is a Persian word that means "hello".